# How to prove the test statistic of the Wilcoxon signed rank test is symmetric about mean

Tags: self-study, nonparametric, wilcoxon-signed-rank, symmetry

How to prove the test statistic of the Wilcoxon signed rank test is symmetric about its mean?

I know that if I want to prove a distribution is symmetric, I need to show
$f(m-t)= f(m+t)$ but $W$ doesn't have a "easy" pmf so I don't know how to do it.

I tried a small number of $n$, and I can easily see that (by calculating all the possibilities) it is symmetric about its mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall how this test works.  The data consist of $n$ ordered pairs $(x_i,y_i),i=1,2,\ldots,n$.  A procedure--the details will not matter--is followed to assign an integer $R_i$ to each pair according to the size of its difference, $|x_i-y_i|$. The test statistic $W$ is the sum of the $R_i$ corresponding to indexes $i$ with a positive difference minus the sum of all $R_i$ corresponding to $i$ with a negative difference.

The null hypothesis is that these differences are realizations of independent variables having a common symmetric distribution about zero.  That's our point of departure, so let's be clear what it means.  Letting $(X,Y)$ be a random variable of which each $(x_i,y_i)$ is an independent realization, "symmetric" means the distributions of $X-Y$ and $-(X-Y) = Y-X$ are the same.

**The conclusion is now immediate:** the symmetry under the null implies we could equally well compute $W$ by reversing each ordered pair; that is, by replacing the data $(x_i,y_i)$ with $(y_i,x_i)$.  This changes all the signs of the $x_i-y_i$, but leaves their sizes the same (whence the $R_i$ do not change), and therefore it merely negates $W$.  Consequently $W$ and its $-W$ have the same distribution, *QED*.